# Posting to a Custom Post Type from front end - user generated content

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, post-meta, front-end

Is there a fast and reliable way of posting to a Custom Post type from the front end? My use case is for creating a daily checkin for a fitness trainer. I have created the necessary fields using ACF. And I was trying to create a front end post form using ACF Frontend for Elementor plugin. But in the plugin my post type doesnt show up at all.
All in all I've tried various methods and I help with something concrete and reliable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Were you able to find any easy solutions? I'm interested in this too.